# Parent directory of... does not exist

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I recently downloaded the new update of Android Studios. I worte a code in the older Version, giraffe, and now when i tried it in the new Version, Hedgehog, and now it doesnt work. The main problem I have is with gradle. it shows me this Bug:
`Parent directory of C:\Users\carin\StudioProjects\arcore-android-sdk\samples\hello_ar_java\build.gradle\.gradle\build-attribution\androidGradlePluginAttributionData.lock does not exist`

I researched alot in the internet and set the distributionUrl to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip because before it was at 8.0.0.

Comment: Open Android Studio project >> File >> Project Structure >> SDK Location >> Gradle settings >> set valid Gradle user home.

Then go to Project >> select desired version